# Formula parse error message

Tags: google-sheets

I've uploaded an Excel doc which worked perfectly in Excel but it's showing a parse error on a formula in Sheets. The formula is:
`=IF(E9<1,C9,IF(AND(E9<=35,E9>=32),C9,IF(AND(E9<32,E9>=1),C9+0.1,IF(E9>35,C9-0.5*(E9-35),not metʺ))))`

Can anyone see why I'm getting an error message?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. The problem is `not metʺ`. The question doesn't include enough details to answer it appropiately. Please add more details as well a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Try:
`=if(E9<1,C9,IF(AND(E9<=35,E9>=32),C9,IF(AND(E9<32,E9>=1),C9+0.1,IF(E9>35,C9-0.5*(E9-35),"not met"))))`

Two things:

- as noted by Ruben, *not met* should be in quotes
- as often happens on moving from one platform to another, sometimes single and double quotation marks are converted as similar-in-appearance (though invalid) characters. In this case, the character following *not met* is a "Unicode Character “ʺ” (U+02BA)" (Modifier Letter Double Prime). Just replacing this (and the missing opening quote) with conventional double quote marks solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you so very much. Problem solved.